# BI Publisher - How to separate values by comma

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I have this row that I'll be showing as comma separated:

```
Name1 number1, Name2 number2, Name3 number3, Name4 number4
```

I put this in a `for-each` loop like:

```
<?for-each-group@inlines:current-group():./NAME?>
```

In the RTF, it is shown as:

```
for-each <?NAME?> <?NUMBER?> , end
```

So I put a comma in the loop, but there is always an extra comma in the end, how do I remove that?

```
Name1 number1, Name2 number2, Name3 number3, Name4 number4,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?for-each-group@inlines:current-group():./NAME?>
<?NAME?> <?NUMBER?><?if@inlines:position()!=last()?>, <?end if?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

[position() function](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/positionfunction.htm)

[last() function](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/lastasindex.htm)